# event change - What is "record mode"?

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I will try to implement a script that will fill some fields when the user press a button.

In SAP [GuiSession Object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiSession%20Object&product=sap_gui_for_windows) documentation, I don't understand what "record mode" is.

> Change `Public Event Change( ByVal Session As GuiSession, ByVal Component As GuiComponent, ByVal CommandArray As Variant )`
>
> In record mode, the session collects changes to elements of the user interface and sends these changes to a listening application whenever server communication is about to start or if the record mode is turned off. The change events are raised immediately before the startRequest event. There is at least one event for every modified element in the recorded session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look right above in [GuiSession Object](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=GuiSession%20Object&product=sap_gui_for_windows):

> Record (Read-write)
> `Public Property Record As Byte`
>
> Setting this property to True enables the recording mode of the session. In this mode changes to elements of the user interface are recorded within SAP GUI and sent to a recording application using the Change event described later.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. THANKS A LOT SANDRA!!!!! It is just a property of that object...